# Running function as a job in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Below is the funtion for just pinging all the machines from a win-form appliaction: 
    I am just pinging all the machines and displaying result in output box and saving it into a csv file:
    As the UI running as Single thread mode, I am not able to perform any other process.
    So please help me to run this function as a job from $Buttonping.Add_Click({pinginfo
    })

```
function pingInfo
{
$pingresults = @()
$outputBox.Clear()
$count1 = 0
$count2 = 0
$Inputarray = $InputBox.Lines
$outputBox.AppendText("PINGING ALL THE MACHINES : PLEASE WAIT TILL THE COMPLETION `n---------------------------------------------------`n")
foreach ($pc in $Inputarray)
{
if(!(Test-Connection -Cn $pc -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))
    {
        $viv = ($pc).ToUpper()
        #$outputBox.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::red
        $outputBox.AppendText("$viv" +"  ----   NOT REACHABLE `r`n")
        #$outputBox.ForeColor = "red"
        $outputBox.ScrollToCaret()
        $Form.refresh()
        $notreachabecount = $count1++
          $details = @{            

            ComputerName     = $pc                
            Status      = "NOT REACHABLE"
                    }
            $pingresults += New-Object PSObject -Property $details 
    }
    else
    {
        $viv = $pc
        $viv = ($pc).ToUpper()
        #$outputBox.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Green
        $outputBox.AppendText("$viv" +"   ----   ONLINE `r`n")
        $outputBox.ScrollToCaret()
        $Form.refresh()
        $reachabecount = $count2++

             $details = @{                        
            ComputerName     = $pc                
            Status      = "ONLINE"
                          }
            $pingresults += New-Object PSObject -Property $details                
    }

}
$pingresults | export-csv -Path $env:TEMP\DIT_Tool_Reports\Ping_Result.csv -NoTypeInformation

$outputBox.AppendText("---------------------------------------------------`r TOTAL ONLINE MACHINE : $count2 `n TOTAL OFFLINE MACHINES $count1")       
$outputBox.ScrollToCaret()
$Form.refresh()
}

# Ping button's form part
$Buttonping = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$Buttonping.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(190,130) 
$Buttonping.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,30) 
$Buttonping.Text = "PING ALL MACHINES" 
$Buttonping.Add_Click({pinginfo
}) 
$Form.Controls.Add($Buttonping)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is ether Powershell Workflow, read more about that my typing the following in a powershell sell:

```
get-help about_Workflows
```

Or you can use this cmdlet from powershell called:

```
get-help Start-Job -full
```

An ex. of "Start-Job":

```
start-job -name process -scriptblock {get-process}
```

Powershell will start Get-process in a job, and you can continue working, or the GUI, on this session.
When the job is done, you can use

```
get-job -name process | Receive-Job
```

To learn more about this cmdlet and it's related cmdlets please go to a powershell and do a get-help on the following
RelatedLinks:
    Get-Job
    Remove-Job
    Resume-Job
    Start-Job
    Stop-Job
    Suspend-Job
    Wait-Job
    about_Jobs
    about_Job_Details